kube-proxy not starting due to nf_conntrack_max
Team
Trying to install k8s but kube-proxy not starting with below error
I0603 18:53:21.135178       1 server_others.go:69] "Using iptables proxy"
I0603 18:53:21.150071       1 node.go:141] Successfully retrieved node IP: 10.97.160.111
I0603 18:53:21.166703       1 conntrack.go:100] "Set sysctl" entry="net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max" value=524288
E0603 18:53:21.166740       1 server.go:537] "Error running ProxyServer" err="open /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max: no such file or directory"
E0603 18:53:21.166760       1 run.go:74] "command failed" err="open /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max: no such file or directory"

I tried to load nf_conntrack but that didn't help
root@staging:/home/hpeoneview# sudo modprobe nf_conntrack
modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_conntrack not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-144-generic

root@staging:/home/hpeoneview# uname -a
Linux hpeoneview-staging 5.4.0-144-generic #161-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 3 14:49:04 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@staging:/home/hpeoneview# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic


With the error showing indicates that that kube-proxy is unable to to access the nf\_conntrack module, which is core component of Linux's Netfilter subsystem used for connection tracking.
You can try this approach to resolve the concern:

Verify the kernel version and module compatibility. It might the pre-loaded module for this version is not compatible
a. You can manually load the module


```bash
 sudo modprobe nf_track_tcp nf_conntrack

This loads both nf_track_tcp (TCP connection tracking) and nf_conntrack modules required by kube-proxy.

              b. You can load the modules auto-load on boot



Edit the file /etc/modules with your preferred text editor (e.g., sudo nano /etc/modules).

Add the module names at the end of the file:
nf_track_tcp
nf_conntrack


Save the file and reboot the system for changes to take effect.



2. Or you can try to update the installation process with a new version

